# spring java web service, asynchronous

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

can an asynchronous web service be achieved with java spring-ws framework like how it's explained in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wlw/docs103/guide/async/callback/ovwAsynchronousWebServices.html)

basically when a client sends a request to the server for the first time, the web service on the server will callback the the client whenever it has information based on the request. so that means the server may reply more than once based on the first initial request from the client.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working with spring-ws?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I didn't managed to implement it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Suggested approach as per my experience:

Asynchronous web services are generally implemented in the following model:
CLIENT SUBMIT REQUEST -> SERVER RETURNS 202 ACCEPTED RESPONSE(polling/JOB URL in header) -> CLIENT KEEP POLLING THE JOB URL -> SERVER RETURNS 200 OK for the JOB URL ALONG WITH JOB RESPONSE IN BODY.

You may need to define few response body for job in progress. When client polls the server and server is still processing the request, the body should contain the IN PROGRESS message in a predefined form for the client. If server finished processing, then the desired response should be available in the body.

Hope it helps!